# How to connect application and Arduino Via Bluetooth in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have Ardunio board.I want to connect this Board through my application Via Bluetooth,and want to send my Tweets in this Ardunio board. Is this possible?

Please reply,

Thank you

Comment: Some time ago I did it, but on Symbian. The task was to pair your phone's BT with Arduino BT, and then simply create serial connection, sending bytes between these two. Worked fine, should work also on Android, but I don't know details of Android's BT serial connection.

Comment: so give me some serial communication link

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you already have a bluetooth shield for your Arduino, if not, then you must get one. Sparkfun carries a variety of different ones, I like to use the following: http://iteadstudio.com/store/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=18%E2%88%8Fucts_id=307

These will allow serial communication with your Arduino. The example bluetooth code: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html can be used "as is" to send messages to the Arduino for testing. You can also easily modify this example to meet your needs.

You will use the device acitity list code to detect your device and get the MAC address which is used to initiate the connection to your bluetooth shield. The service code allows you to connect, send and receive messages from the bluetooth device.

On the Arduino side you simply need to read and write via serial to send and receive the data.